How to nest functions using python
def getValues():
    a = input('first')
    b = input('second')
    return (a, b)

def sum(x,y):
    result = x + y
    print(result)

sum(getValues())

i expected the sum to be executed with the values returned by getValues, but idt does not works

Just a typo.  You need sum(*getValues()).  The "*" tells Python to expand the items in your tuple to be separate arguments.

Also, for a sum, you'll need to convert the values to numbers before doing the math or you'll just concatenate them.
